# How do i drop voltage in series?

Tags: amplifier

I have a 12v PSU output voltage that uses around 9A, i need to decrease this voltage to 11v but keep the amperage the same, any ideas? thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? What load are you driving that will take the same current at 11V as it does at 12V?

Comment: Sounds like an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Try to explain what EXACTLY you want to achieve and why, not how.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to adjust the power supply to output 11V in the first place.

Many power supplies are adjustable something like ±10% around their nominal output voltage to begin with. This falls within that range, so look for a trimmer pot and turn it.

Even if the feedback is done with fixed resistors, it should be easy to identify the two resistors that form the feedback divider and change one of them (or replace one or both of them with a trimmer).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a few Diodes.

Diodes have (almost) a constant voltage drop, you can search on digikey from the part to find a diode with the required 9A rating and having a voltage drop of 1V, or 2 diodes with 0.5V voltage drop.

[This one for example.](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/10A02-T/10A02-TDITR-ND/1933911)

You could also look for Linear Voltage Regulator, but the 9A requirement and small voltage drop (1V) might make difficult to find a part.

The small voltage drop and high current probably makes it also difficult to find a switching regulator.